# How to implement Hilbert Transform on image

Tags: matlab

I am looking for the 2D Hilbert Transform. I want the Hilbert spectrum for gray scale images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB already has support for the Hilbert transform (it's part of the [Signal Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/signal/index.html)) - you just need to make sure that you [take the imaginary part of the result of the `hilbert` function](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3134-hilbert-transform).

Comment: Hilbert 1D time series signal i guess. How could we apply it for image. Can u elaborate the imaginary part of the result as u mentioned in your previous answer

Comment: Click on the second link embedded in the answer for more info. You can pass a 2D array to `hilbert` but I believe it just does a 1D Hilbert transform on the columns, so you'd need to call it a second time on the transpose transform from the first call.